# IntelliJ IDEA shows classes and methods as unused after power failure

Tags: intellij-idea, code-analysis

So electricity went off in the building and my PC shut down. When it came back up and I restarted my PC I noticed this problem in IntelliJ IDEA. Now every method/class which is not used within the same class (public methods used in different classes and pretty much any class) shows a warning "Class xxx is never used" or "Method xxx is never used". Needless to say "Find usages" (alt+f7 by default) does not work as well and can't find anything. Tried maven rebuilding, tried opening the project cleanly, tried rebuilding/recompiling, nothing works.
Any help would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: I'd recommend deleting the .idea folder and all IntelliJ project files and recreating the project from existing sources.  Should be easy if you have Maven - just create the project by importing the existing pom.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried **file -> Invalidate caches/restart**? This has fixed similar issues for me in the past

You can read more on the feature here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/cleaning-system-cache.html